# Start a process on a different tty

Tags: bash, tty

After about an hour of Googling this, I can't *believe* nobody has actually asked this question before...

So I've got a script running on TTY1. How do I make that script launch some arbitrary program on TTY2?

- I found `tty`, which tells you which TTY you're currently on.
- I found `writevt`, which writes a single line of text onto a different TTY.
- I found `chvt`, which changes which TTY is currently displayed.

I don't want to *display* TTY2. I just want the main script to continue executing normally, but if I manually switch to TTY2 I can interact with the second program.

Comment: From TTY1, Have you tried `[command] > /dev/tty2` (you have to already logged-in to tty2)?

Comment: this could be a XYproblem ... what are you trying to achieve? what is the overall goal?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
setsid sh -c 'exec command <> /dev/tty2 >&0 2>&1'
```

As long as nothing else is using the other TTY (`/dev/tty2` in this example), this should work. This includes a `getty` process that may be waiting for someone to login; having more than one process reading its input from a TTY *will* lead to unexpected results.

`setsid` takes care of starting the command in a new session.

Note that `command` will have to take care of setting the `stty` settings correctly, e.g. turn on "cooked mode" and `onlcr` so that outputting a newline will add a carriage return, etc.

Comment: That is not correct. You mix up the controlling terminal with `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr`. `ps` easily shows that `command` does not have a controlling terminal at all in your case.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, a session leader takes control of a terminal as soon as it opens it. The problem was that the terminal device was not open by the session leader. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tested with `sleep 1000` and it still doesn't work here. I used a pseudo tty, though (shouldn't make a difference, I guess).

Comment: @HaukeLaging How exactly did you do it? Did that terminal not have a controlling session already (the _As long as nothing else is using the other TTY_ part)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I ran `setsid sh -c 'exec sleep 1000 <>/dev/pts/4 >&0 2>&1'` in a terminal emulator window. `/dev/pts/4` is another terminal emulator window (same user, with `bash` running).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, then you're not meeting wurtel's requirement. You cannot take control of a terminal if it already has a controller. Try on `/dev/tty15`

Comment: This worked for me when nohup did not.

Comment: This works, for example, with command as `ls $HOME`, but not for `cd $HOME`: it does not change the working folder of the other TTY. This is probably because it "opens a new session". OTOH, `exec cd $HOME <> /dev/tty2 >&0 2>&1` just quits the tty where this exec is being executed (??!!).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit `cd` is not an independent command (so it could not become a new process), it is a builtin command for a shell (e.g., `bash`), to change its current working directory. You could check with `which cd`, the output should be empty or contain some error message. So when you run `exec cd ...`, the command actually failed. Besides, you might read more about `exec` to know what happens it is executed.

Comment: Yes. What I tried to say is that along this question we have been mixing things: executing a command in another tty vs redirecting outputs. I still don't know if it is possible or not to ask another shell process in other tty to do something, e.g., 'cd' to a new folder.

Answer (score 6):

On the second tty there will be normally a program running, either some login program or some shell like bash. If you want interaction you either would have to replace the login program with yours, or tell a shell to run the program as if the program was started from the commandline.

A more simple solution, IMO, would be to start a `tmux` session after logging into the second screen and then use:

```
tmux send yourcommand ENTER
```

to start the program in the `tmux` session which will display after you switch to the second terminal.

Answer (score 6):

I just made a discovery:

[How can I launch applications from 2 ttys on launch?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58445/how-can-i-launch-applications-from-2-ttys-on-launch)

One of the comments mentions something called `openvt`. This command appears to do the exact thing I'm after!

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_openvt.htm

Unless anyone knows different, I think *this* is probably the "correct" way to do this.

(I just tried it, and it seems to work fine - even though `getty` is running, it picks the next unused terminal. I guess VTs don't get "opened" until you switch to one to try to log in...)

Answer (score 3):

i start a new graphical session on the vt5 with the follow command

```
xinit "/usr/bin/<binary_executable>" -- :1 vt5
```

for example :

```
xinit "/usr/bin/playonlinux" -- :1 vt5
```

If you want to launch a graphical application on already active graphical session you can do with :

```
DISPLAY=:0 "/usr/bin/playonlinux"
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was trying to figure out (DISPLAY=:0)

Answer (score 0):

start bash on different tty:

```
setsid agetty --autologin root  --noclear 19200 ttyS1 linux
```