# /etc/inittab: auto login on ttyS0

Tags: login, tty, serial-port, getty

in my `/etc/inittab`, I have this line:

```
T0:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

which gives me `getty` on serial console where I can log in.

How can I specify that instead `getty`, I get automatically shell ? In other words, how can I have root console without having to login with username and password.

From what I found, I should use `login -f`:

```
/bin/login -f root
```

but I am not sure how to tell login I am using `ttyS0` and also how to specify the correct baud rate `115200`.

Comment: You might take a look at this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170063/start-a-process-on-a-different-tty

Comment: The questioner has stated elsewhere that xe is using Debian 10, configured to use the sysvinit-core package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the -a (autologin) option in inittab and kill -HUP 1 (init):

```
T0:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty -a root -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

Comment: that works. Thank you.